# C# Узнать скорость вычесления на GPU (хешрейт)

Tags: c#, .net, хеширование, gpu

Всем доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся я с такой вот проблемой:
Есть необходимость при помощи C# Net2.0 рассчитать скорость видеокарты, так как ее обычно считают при майнинге, нужен какой-нибудь алгоритм, который мог бы просчитать сколько хешей в секунду посчитает GPU и вернул среднее значение за 10 секунд например.
Буду очень благодарен за ответ!)

Comment: Ну, запустите расчет хешей и посчитайте сколько она выдает в единицу времени. Нет такого универсального метода, т.к. "хеш" бывает разным и рассчитывается он по-разному.

Comment: немного почитал об этом и вправду.. интересно, откуда сайты для расчета хешрейта берут инфу?.. наверное от производителей. и можно ли как-то вывести коэффициенты алгоритмов - чтобы получать хешрейт вроде  гигафлопсы * коэфф = хешрейт

Comment: https://whattomine.com/ и https://technical.city/ru/video/GeForce-GTX-1080-Ti . На основе данных с этих сайтов я смог вывести некоторые коэффициенты для видеокарт. Точность: 3 знака после запятой, 1080TI не берется в расчет из-за ее слишком большого потенциала, который завысит средний коэфф. Для RandomX это 0.079 в среднем. Разброс от 0.076 до 0.086. Данные основаны на 6 видеокартах. Думаю это сможет мне помочь

Comment: `наверное от производителей` Производители не измеряют производительность в хешрейте. Т.к. видеокарта - графическая, то измеряют по скорости заполнения, например в гигапикселях и в гигатекселях, а из этих показателей можно примерно посчитать производительность во FLOPS.

Answer (score 0):

**Универсального алгоритма нет**
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177631/%d0%93%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%9f - пролил на это свет, спасибо.

> немного почитал об этом и вправду.. интересно, откуда сайты для расчета хешрейта берут инфу?.. наверное от производителей. и можно ли как-то вывести коэффициенты алгоритмов - чтобы получать хешрейт вроде гигафлопсы * коэфф = хешрейт – Daniil Petrenko 29 минут назад
>   whattomine.com и technical.city/ru/video/GeForce-GTX-1080-Ti . На основе данных с этих сайтов я смог вывести некоторые коэффициенты для видеокарт. Точность: 3 знака после запятой, 1080TI не берется в расчет из-за ее слишком большого потенциала, который завысит средний коэфф. Для RandomX это 0.079 в среднем. Разброс от 0.076 до 0.086. Данные основаны на 6 видеокартах. Думаю это сможет мне помочь - Daniil Petrenko 1 минуту назад